# Nginx micro caching with JQuery callback

Tags: php, jquery, caching, nginx

I have micro caching setup with my Nginx server to cache an API for 2 seconds. However, each time a request is made to the API, a different url is seen by Nginx because of the attached jQuery callback parameter.

**Example:**

`api.example.com/get_heats.php?sheet=105&callback=jQuery222018438785197213292_1475857341748&_=1475857342048`

and

`api.example.com/get_heats.php?sheet=105&callback=jQuery222018438785197213292_1475857341748&_=1475857342049`

should return the same values for 2 seconds because they are both referencing sheet 105, but they don't because the callback and _ parameters are changing with each request. Is there a way for Nginx to ignore any of the other parameters?

Comment: post your nginx caching configuration? there maybe be a way to match with regex disregarding the jquery parameter

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/545009/nginx-ignore-query-string-for-caching-certain-files

Comment: cOle2 - that link caches url's without any of the parameters. I need to cache the URL with one parameter and none of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try out the following code,

```
server {
   ...
   location ~ \.php$ {
      ...
      set $cache_key $request_uri;
      ...
      if ($args ~ "sheet") {
         set $cache_key $cache_key|$arg_sheet;
      }
      ...
      fastcgi_cache_key $cache_key;
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

References : [Learn to implement microcaching](https://www.techromance.com/2015/11/11/microcaching-nginx-web-server/), [fastcgi_cache_key](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache_key)